# Lightning Email Template - "Click the Source icon to add HTML code" option missing

Tags: lightning-email-template

I am trying to see the html of my Lightning email template.  According to the documentation, I should see an option "Click the Source icon to add HTML code"  I don't see this option.  Thoughts?  Directions on where it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML source for Lightning email templates cannot be seen when you are creating a template when composing an email.  Instead, you need to go to Email Templates via Application Launcher.  When editing a template that way, you can see the source option.